# How to find a kill and processes with subprocess

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pid

I am trying to find and kill processes like

```
subprocess.run(['kill', '$(pidof random_comand)'])
```

But I'm getting the output

```
kill: failed to parse argument: '$(pidof random_command)'
```

Though I can do the same thing from the CLI and kill the processes, as `kill $(pidof random_command)`. How is it done with `subprocess.run`?

Comment: `$(pidof random_name)` is substituted by shell with output of the command and then passed as arguments to `kill`. You can do the same or run e.g. with `/bin/bash -c`

Comment: It works like that in the CLI, but doesn't seem to with subprocess.

Comment: Because `kill` receives string `$(pidof random_command)`, not a list of pids.

Comment: Yes, so how to get the list of PIDs, are you suggesting adding  `'/bin/bash', '-c'` before `'kill'`?

Comment: As one of possible ways, yes. Something like `subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'pidof random_comand')`

Comment: I get  `Not a directory: '/bin/bash/'`

Comment: `kill pidof random_command` does not work in the CLI, I get `-bash: kill: pidof: arguments must be process or job IDs`

Comment: In shell you have to use `kill $(pidof random_command)`. In python, where did you get `/` after `bash`?

Comment: missed that, ok, I removed the `/`, but `subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'kill', 'pidof', 'random_command'])` did not kill the processes

Comment: Why did you split last string into three? It must be one argument.

Comment: Ok, tried that, `subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'kill pidof random_command'])`, it did not kill the processes

Comment: `subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'kill $(pidof random_comand)'])`

Comment: ok that worked, thanks, you can put that in an answer for points lol, if you want